# New here: Issues linking HTML to JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've gotten the code to a workable level in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/matthewbonney/ggu53oy0/), but I am still having issues with getting the code together so I can put it in an actual site.

I'm embedding the form in a sharepoint site, I know I read the JS might need to be linked in externally as a file.

Form Function: HTML Inputs are strung together by the javascript and then displayed via an alert.

```
<HTML>
<body>
<head>
<script language=“javascript”>
var button = document.getElementById('test');
var date = document.getElementById('1');
var contact = document.getElementById('2');
var contacttype = document.getElementById('3');
var os = document.getElementById('4');
var devicetype = document.getElementById('5');
var device = document.getElementById('6');
var reason = document.getElementById('7');
var comments = document.getElementById('8');

button.onclick = function () {
    var str = "Date: " + date.value + "   " + "Contact: " + contact.value + "   " + "Insured or Agent: " + contacttype.value + "   " + "Operating System: " + os.value + "   " + "Tablet or Phone: " + devicetype.value + "   " + "Device Name: " + device.value + "   " + "Reason fo Call: " + reason.value + "   " + "Additional Comments: " + comments.value;
    alert(str);

};
</script>
</head>
<h1> SR Template
</h1>
<label>Date:
    <input id="1" />
</label>
<br />
<label>Contact:
    <input id="2" />
</label>
<br>
<label>Insured or Agent:
    <input id="3" />
</label>
<br>
<label>Operating System:
    <input id="4" />
</label>
<br>
<label>Tablet or Phone:
    <input id="5" />
</label>
    <br>
    <label>Device Name:
    <input id="6" />
</label>
        <br>
    <label>Reason for call:
    <input id="7" />
</label>
            <br>
    <label>Additional Comments:
    <input id="8" />
</label>

<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>


</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I have heard of problems occuring using only a number as an id for an element. I'm not sure exactly what your question is but I might start with making those id's something like "input1" or "i1" etc...

Comment: @SnoApps IDs can start with a digit, and `getElementById` supports it. The only problem is that CSS identifiers can't begin with a digit, but it can be escaped.

Comment: @Oriol Oh ok, I didn't know that. I'd still play it safe and also make it look cleaner and more organized by adding descriptive ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
language=“javascript”
```

You can't delimit attribute values with angled quotes, so that is an unrecognised language so the browser will ignore the script entirely.

It's also HTML 3.2, which was obsoleted in 1998. This is 2015. Write HTML 5. Don't include a language attribute at all.

---

```
var button = document.getElementById('test');
```

There is no element with that id before the script element.

Your code is not in a function that gets called later.

The element doesn't exist when you try to run that code.

Move the script to after the elements you are trying to get out of the DOM or wrap it in an onload function as you have configured JSFiddle to do.

Comment: Ah! Beat me to it! @Quentin

Answer (score 0):

In your `<script>` you have `language=“javascript”` those quotes are fancy quotes from probably Microsoft Word. 
Your issue **might** be that it's not standard quotes... like this: "